# Can't get Passenger to start Rails 4 app in staging environment

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

My app is running on this stack:

Ubuntu 12.04.3
nginx 1.4.4
passenger 4.0.33
rvm 1.25.12
ruby 2.1.0p0

nginx.conf file:

```
http {
  passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.33;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.0/ruby;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name redacted;
    root /home/deploy/apps/redacted/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env staging;
  }
}
```

When I try to start the app, it fails because it starts in the production environment and I have no database.yml entry for production, only for staging.

How can I get my app to start in staging? I also have other apps running on the same VM in production mode, so I can't blanket set the env['RACK_ENV'] or env['RAILS_ENV'].

Comment: Can you try [Passenger Standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html)? Does it work there?

Comment: Thanks @Hongli, would installing and running passenger standalone on the same VM interfere with the existing passenger/nginx setup?

Comment: No, it would not interfere. You can run as many Passenger Standalone instances as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, the solution was to specify the environment in the nginx config file: [`rails_env "staging";`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#RailsEnv)

You might want to put `staging` in quotes on your config.