# Nginx + Phusion Passenger + Rails = staging ENV won't be set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am having trouble making phusion passenger see that the server is set for staging instead of production.

I have changed `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<my app>`

using sudo nano `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<my app>`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <app name>;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name <app name>;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env staging;
  rails_env staging;
  root /home/deploy/apps/<app name>/current/public;

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

basically added/changed lines

`passenger_app_env staging;
  rails_env staging;`

but still not working, is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: I assume you restarted nginx afterwards?  Passengers docs suggest what you've got should work.

Comment: @j-dexx yeah i did

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554402/cant-get-passenger-to-start-rails-4-app-in-staging-environment) suggests putting the environment in quotes.  Wasn't accepted though so don't know if it works.

Comment: hey @j-dexx finally fixed it thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference after two hours of searching i found out that

`rails_env "staging";` line of code

should be added to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` instead.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: You are a life saver - but this only happens on Ubuntu 18. on Ubuntu 16 - it picks up the ENV from capistrano

Comment: Glad i could help someone :)